# "The government 'is' always changing 'their' mind" in AmEng

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, formality, dialects

Why would using the construct "is/their" instead of "is/its" in the following examples likely be frowned upon by some native speakers and marked as incorrect on tests?

> *The class **is** working on **its** assignment*. (AmEng)
>
> *The class **is/are** working on **its/their** assignment*. (BrEng)
>
> *The class **is** working on **their** assignment*. (disputed usage)

-and-

> *The government **is** always changing **its** mind*. (AmEng)
>
> *The government **is/are** always changing **its/their** minds*. (BrEng)
>
> *The government **is** always changing **their** mind*. (disputed usage)

-and-

> *The team **is** putting on **its** uniforms*. (chiefly AmEng)
>
> *The team **are** putting on **their** uniforms*. (chiefly BrEng)
>
> *The team **is** putting on **their** uniforms*. (disputed usage)

-and-

> *The Smith family **is** at the beauty parlor getting **its** hair and nails done for the wedding*. (chiefly AmEng)
>
> *The Smith family **are** at the beauty parlor getting **their** hair and nails done for the wedding*. (chiefly BrEng)
>
> *The Smith family **is** at the beauty parlor getting **their** hair and nails done for the wedding*. (disputed usage)

On the other hand, why might other native speakers consider this usage to be acceptable?

Comment: Although "a person"/"their" is now a standard gender-neutral form in U.S. English, "a thing"/"their" is far less widely accepted—and the reason for that difference in acceptance, I think, is that the older form "a thing"/"its" doesn't raise gender-bias objections. It is certainly not less logical as a matter of number consistency to say "a thing"/"their" than to say "a person"/"their"; but the latter became widespread only because it did sidestep the problem of making "a person," "someone," etc., male. But if you already have a gender-neutral form with "a thing"/"its," why change it?

Comment: Maybe it's cultural.  Maybe it's because it's *America United*, *America Inc.* even.  We create imaginary entities, like corporations, that don't really exist and then count them as a singular thing rather than the plurality of individuals who comprise that imaginary thing.  We lend more credence and acknowledgment to the intangible whole, to the union, to the incorporated yet incorporate body, than we do to those people who make up that whole, that union, that corporation.  Ergo, the government *is* instead of the government *are*, and the class's possession is *its* instead of *theirs*.

Comment: I'm saying the reason for the disparity is likely sublime, driven by an an entire mindset of unity, of many into one.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Would it be not uncommon to hear in the U.S., "'Where's the Smith family right now?' B: '"It's/It is" at the beauty parlor getting "its" hair and nails done for the wedding'"?

Comment: The BrEng attribution seems misplaced for the class and government examples; the family examples for BrE seem more natural (than the class and government ones).

Comment: @Elian : In America, you would only ever hear, "Where's the Smith family right now?"  You would *never* hear it said, "Where are the Smith family right now?"  I don't know what your second question is.  *It* wouldn't go to a beauty parlor and get *its* nails done.  An *it* isn't human.  An *it* has neither feet to take it anywhere nor nails to get done anywhere.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: I know an "it" isn't human. Neither is "its" in "The Smith family is at the beauty parlor getting "its" hair done" actually. What I'm trying to point out is, if it's ungrammatical to say "The Smith family "is" at the beauty parlor getting "their" hair done," then it should also be ungrammatical to say, A: 'Where "is" the Smith family right now?' B: '"They" are at the beauty parlor getting "their" hair done." ;-)

Comment: @Elian : Okay.  Now I see what you're driving at.  Sorry that I couldn't suss it out before.  I must be having a thick day.  Maybe that's why I'm going to have to chew on what you said for a bit.  Mull it over.  In my American mind, when I say something like, "My family isn't here right now--they're all at the beauty parlor getting their hair done," I've switched subjects. I'm not thinking of my family as a single unit in the second half but as several people. In the first half, I say "is," but in the second, I say "are." I'm going to have to mentally kick around some other scenarios though.

Comment: Where do you get this 'disputed usage' (and where do you get these sentences and labels)? They are not disputed; they are clearly wrong.

Comment: @Mitch See the last comment under BenjaminHarman's answer. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300082/the-class-is-are-all-working-on-a-project-together/300087?noredirect=1#comment675661_300087

Comment: In American English, should it be *The team is putting on its uniforms?* Or *The team is putting on their uniforms?* Does anybody think the first one is okay? It sounds insulting to me: you don't call people *it*.

Comment: @Mitch: if you can't say *The Smith family is at the beauty parlor getting their hair done?* then what is the correct usage. *The Smith family* doesn't get *its hair done.* (Let me say the first and third examples are perfectly correct with *its* in AmE.)

Comment: @Elian I don't understand what Peter is referring to because your comments don't seem to exist.

Comment: @PeterShor OK. That makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disputed usage is due to how although team, government, class, etc., are singular nouns, suggesting that they should be conjugated with the singular verb "is", they are made up of many people. And so, to say that the government is always changing their mind makes sense when you think about so many people in the government changing their mind, but not if you adhere to the strict usage of singular verbs with a singular noun.

Answer (score 1):

Why would such examples be "frowned upon"?  Because careful speakers/writers often place a high premium on consistency.  The "disputed" usages you cite have an apparently paradoxical problem of grammatical number.

> The government is always changing **their** mind.

If *government* is singular, which is indicated by a singular verb, then where do the (apparently plural) elements referenced by *their* come from?  It's the same issue that causes some careful speakers/writers to object to "singular they" as a neutral pronoun with singular antecedent, even though it's been around and common for centuries and rarely creates confusion.

In certain contexts, particularly in written prose in a more formal style, this sort of linguistic analysis is easier to do than in fast conversation.  In such cases, such inconsistency in number would generally be branded as "awkward" at best (and likely considered "wrong" by many).  If I wrote a sentence like one of your examples, I would probably rephrase it to get my point across clearly, rather than simply changing the number of the pronoun (which, as I will argue, alters the meaning in some cases).

---

Why would the usage be acceptable?  Well, mostly because the meaning is very clear in spoken colloquial English.  In the above example, *the government* is not a monolithic entity: it is composed of individual people, who each have to make decisions.  Nevertheless, there is some sense of a collective *mind* that is being changed in the idiom *changing [his/her/its] mind*.  In this case, it may just take a few votes switching sides to move an issue for the entire government.  Hence, the *government* (as a whole) will be changed (as a whole, in its *mind*) by a few voting members (*they*) making a shift.

It is perhaps overly concise, packing in a subtle reference to a collective noun's individual components while maintaining a sense of the change of the whole.  Again, if I wanted to express that in formal prose, I'd reword it.  Simply changing the sentence to

> The government is always changing **its** mind.

does not fix the problem.  Rather it alters the meaning to emphasize the monolithic character of the government, as opposed to the individual members.

The various examples given in the question pose similar issues, though I think the justification for the usage is less clear.  Take the first example:

> The class is working on **their** assignment.

Unlike the government example, what additional subtlety of meaning is given here by the incongruity of grammatical number?  I can't really think of one, and this sentence actually sounds the most awkward to me of the examples given.  I would tend to write

> The class is working on **its** assignment.

though I can imagine someone saying:

> The class is working on **their assignments**.

In that case, there is a mid-sentence shift in number from the emphasis on the whole (*class is*) to individual members and their individual materials (*their assignments*).  A similar thing happens in the last example:

> The Smith family is at the beauty parlor getting **their** hair and
>   nails done for the wedding.

In this case, it is somewhat nonsensical to say that a family has **its** hair and nails done, since families as entities generally aren't seen as possessing hair and nails.  These are, rather, the possessions of individuals.  Note also that here, as in my example of *their assignments* (and the question's example of *their uniforms*), *hair and nails* is plural.  It's not as obvious, since even an individual has *hair and nails*, but I think the sentence would sound quite weird if we just pluralized the pronoun but not the noun:

> The Smith family is at the plastic surgeon getting **their nose** done
>   for the wedding.

At a minimum, we'd need to change it to *noses*, assuming more than one *nose* was being altered.

And while we're creating absurd sentences, imagine:

> The **government** is at the beauty parlor getting **their** hair and nails
>   done.

Even if the government were [subjunctive! not plural] composed of a large number of people who all went off to the beauty parlor one day, I would argue that this sentence still wouldn't make sense.  Why?  Because "getting hair and nails done" is not a common activity of governments, and even if individual members might do so, it is not in any way related to governmental function.  On the other hand, class members do do assignments, team members do put on uniforms, and family members often do go *en masse* to beauty parlors before weddings.

My point is that in all of these cases, a reference both to the collective whole and to individual members acting as individuals could make sense and hence might get thrown into the same sentence together.  The less stereotypical the actions (and the shorter the sentence), the more awkward the usage becomes.  To me,

> The team is eating **their** lunches.

sounds more strange than

> The team is putting on **their** uniforms.

Basically, I feel like there's a combination of "shorthand" synecdoche (*team* is just faster to say than *team members*) and mid-sentence correction going on in many of these examples.  Careful speakers might actually interrupt themselves and start the sentence over with consistent grammatical number, but practical English speakers will just plow through and assume the shift in number is clear from context (which it mostly is in these examples).  Meanwhile, they don't breach American speech protocols for collective nouns (*The family are...* sounds odd to Americans in most contexts) while gaining the benefits of concise speech that both references a larger communal entity acting collectively and also recognizes the individuality of its constituents.

---

But hey, don't just listen to me.  Over at Language Log, a [post from a decade ago](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001874.html) addressed the issue (and specifically the word *family*).  The argument there, as I tried to make here, is to consider the individual logic of the sentence and what multiple meanings it is trying to get across by changing number in midstream:

> If someone's logically-concocted "rule" ... tries to stop me from saying
>   what I mean in this case, I perceive it not as a principle to be
>   learned and obeyed, but as a tyranny to be resisted.